# Will reading/writing an int value from/to a file using byte-oriented stream such as FileInputStream/FileOutputStream access the buffer/disk 4 times?

Tags: java, io

Sample Code is :-

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteInt{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    WriteInt obj = new WriteInt();
    obj.write();
    }

    public void write(){
    File file = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    int [] arr = {6};
    try{
    file= new File("CheckSize.txt");
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    for(int i =0; i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to write to file:-"+ file);
        out.write(arr[i]);
    }

    }
    catch(IOException ioex){
    ioex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
    if(out != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Closing the stream");
        try{
        out.close();
        }   
        catch(IOException ioex){
        ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("Stream not open");
        }   
    }
    }

    }
```

Since I am using Byte-Oriented Stream to write data to a file; My Question is that will the data be written to file in 4 steps (1 byte) in each step. Considering `int` to be of 4 bytes. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can read about it in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int))

Comment: Maybe you could check by yourself by trying it?

Comment: how can this be checked?

Comment: write one int to the file like you are doing it and look at the file afterwards (maybe with a hex editor)

Comment: You aren't writing an int at all. You are writing a byte. That only takes one write.

Comment: @EJP, so would it be correct if I say that int is casted to byte first by the write method and then the converted byte is written to the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

out.write(arr[i]) will write only the lowest byte of int. The best solution is to use java.io.DataOutputStream which has writeInt(int) method.

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file"));
    out.writeInt(arr[i]);
```

Comment: there will be lost of precision; so can this be assumed that int is first converted to byte than written to file?

Comment: see OutputStream.write(int b) API, it says: "Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for <code>write</code> is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument <code>b</code>. The 24 high-order bits of <code>b</code> are ignored."

Comment: Int does get converted to byte but here in your case value which needs to be written is within the range of byte so even if the truncation occurs there is no loss of precision.But even if the value 127(more than max value of byte) there will be no loss of precision.
Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402568/how-write-method-in-fileoutputstream-truncates-the-int-type-argument

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are using OutputStream.write(int)
which writes only byte representation of provided number - only one byte is writen, take a look to [OutputStream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). So your file will contain only one byte with 6. If you will try to write a number that is more than 255 - you can expect an exception.

Basically OutputStream requires its subclasses to implement only write(int) method, so other OutputStream methods sends theirs bytes to write(int). However all write methods in FileOutputStream are overridden and utilizes buffered native call that probably tries to send all data at a time.

Comment: I was expecting an exception but to my surprise number 257 is taken as 1.

Comment: I have checked FileOutputStream source code. It simply utilizes buffered call of native library (check writeBytes method here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.java.html). So all writing methods sends data through this one.