# how write method in FileOutputStream truncates the int type argument

Tags: java, byte, fileinputstream

write() method in FileOutputStream takes an int but truncates the first 3 bytes and writes the byte to stream.
If a file contains characters whose ASCII value is more than 127 and bytes are read from it and then written to output stream(another text file) how will it display it because in Java bytes can have a max value of +127.

If a text file(input.text) has character '›' whose ASCII value is 155.
An input stream,input, reads from it :
`int in= new FileInputStream("input.txt").read();//in = 155`

Now it writes to another text file(output.txt)

`new FileOutputStream("output.txt").write(in);`

Here integer "in" is truncated to byte which will have corresponding decimal value : -101.
How it successfully manages to write the character to file even though information about it seems to have been lost?

Just now i went through the description of write(int) method in java docs and what i observed was

> The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are **ignored**.

So i believe that contrary to what i thought earlier(the int in write() is truncated as would happen while downcasting an integer to byte for values greater than 127) the 24 high order bits are only ignored and only 8 least significant bits are considered.
No truncation and conversion to byte occurs.
I guess i am correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion is caused by the fact that specs for character sets typically take the view that bytes are unsigned, while Java treats bytes as signed.

In fact `155` as an unsigned byte is `-101` as a signed byte.  (`256 - 101 == 155`).  The bit patterns are identical.  It is just a matter of whether you *think* of them as signed or unsigned.

How the truncation is coded is implementation specific.  But there is no loss of information ... assuming that you had an 8-bit code in the first place.

Comment: it means that only java considers bytes as signed but the underlying system(execution engine) which actually does the job of writing it to file treats them as signed and looks at only the bit pattern.
Also the truncation does occur i.e. somewhere in the write() method code like this : "byte b=(byte)b" where b is the int passed to write as argument, can be found.Argument to write is actually typecast to a byte.

Comment: Yes. The truncation does occur, but it doesn't result in any loss of information ... assuming you were only trying to write an 8-bit code point.  If you want to look at the details for how it happens, Google for the source code.